# How to retrieve employee Id from Azure AD using Django?

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-active-directory

[image: Image of employee id]

I am trying to retrieve the Employee Id using Django as shown above. This platform is derived from Azure Active Directory. What are some of the parameters or ways to **CALL** the Employee ID?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Microsoft Graph API** to call the user and get the employeeID. And for that to call from your Django app you have to use ADAL library.

**Code:**

```
import adal,requests

url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token'
data = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': "your_client_id",
    'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
    'client_secret': "your_client_secret"
}
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
token = r.json().get('access_token')

url = ’https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0//users?&$select=displayName,jobTitle,employeeID’
headers = {
    'Content-Type' : 'application\json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token)
    ‘ConsistencyLevel’ : ’eventual’
}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
result = r.json()
print(result)
```

I have tested the URL using Graph explorer and its working .

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0//users?&$select=displayName,jobTitle,employeeID
```

The above Url will provide all the users present in your AAD and select only display name , jobtitle and employeeID and display it .

[image]

**Note :** After you have registered the app in Azure AD then in API permission, make sure the app has User.Readall permission set to get the details.

**Reference:**

[django - How to access the Azure AD Groups and user details using python? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51859504/how-to-access-the-azure-ad-groups-and-user-details-using-python)

[AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python: ADAL for Python (github.com)](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python)

[Querying Microsoft Graph API with Python | by Ephraim Mwai | Towards Data Science](https://towardsdatascience.com/querying-microsoft-graph-api-with-python-269118e8180c)