# How do I integrate specific attribute in Django

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-active-directory

If I used this line in the PowerShell:
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "elton.tan@straitsconstruction.com").ExtensionProperty["employeeId"]

I will get the employee id
[image]

How do I integrate this into Django?

```
**This is my graph helper.py**

graph_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/'

def get_user(token):
  # Send GET to /me
  user = requests.get(
    '{0}/me'.format(graph_url),
     
    
    headers={  
      'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(token)
    },
    params={
      '$select': 'displayName,mail,mailboxSettings,userPrincipalName,department, employeeId'
      
    })
  
  return user.json()



**This is my HTML**

<p>{{user.employeeId}} </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**As this already has been answer by MSFT Sikumars over Q&A.**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/502266/how-do-i-retrieve-the-employee-id-using-django.html

> Could you please confirm graph_url being used to get user details by
> django? If you are using V1.0 which is
> (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0) then you need to switch it to MS
> Graph beta endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/ because
> “employeeId” is only available in MS Graph beta endpoint as of today.
>
> You can check this from Microsoft Graph Explorer as shown below :
> [image]
>
> Reference:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python?tutorial-step=3

And if you are using V1.0 you have to hard code the URL like this:
url = ’https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0//users?&$select=displayName,jobTitle,employeeID’

Reference: [How to retrieve employee Id from Azure AD using Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68646165/how-to-retrieve-employee-id-from-azure-ad-using-django)