# How to access azure AD using python SDK

Tags: python-3.x, azure-active-directory

I am new to Azure, I want to write a python function to access Azure AD and list the existing groups there, I am facing issues logging into azure. I have been working in AWS there I use boto3 as SDK and I use the command line or programmatic acess. Following is the code that I have

```
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import UserPassCredentials

# See above for details on creating different types of AAD credentials
credentials = UserPassCredentials(
            'user@domain.com',      # The user id I use to login into my personal account
            'my_password',          # password of that account 
            resource="https://graph.windows.net"
    )

tenant_id = "82019-1-some-numbers"

graphrbac_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(
    credentials,
    tenant_id
)
```

I want to know which is professional way of logging into azure, how do i list the groups present in my azure AD, what code changes do i have to do for that

Snapshot of the API permission
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve list of Azure AD groups, make sure to grant **`Directory.Read.All`** for your application like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your App -> API permissions*

[image]

You can make use of below script to get the list of Azure AD Groups by **Krassy** in this [***SO Thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51859504/how-to-access-the-azure-ad-groups-and-user-details-using-python):

```py
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id="Client_ID",
    secret="Secret",
    resource="https://graph.microsoft.com",
    tenant = 'tenant.onmicrosoft.com'
)
tenant_id = 'tenant_id'
graphrbac_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(credentials,tenant_id)
groups = graphrbac_client.groups.list()
for g in groups:
     print(g.display_name)
```

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Azure Python SDK - Interact with Azure AD by Joy Wang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58260616/azure-python-sdk-interact-with-azure-ad)

[How to access the list of Azure AD Groups using python by Will Shao - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30849305/how-to-access-the-list-of-azure-ad-groups-using-python)

Comment: Hi I don't have any apps as of now, I recently created azure account.  Could you please tell me how I can  create a secret key and access Azure AD groups locally ? without having any app ?

Comment: You can make use of [**Azure PowerShell**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadgroup?view=azureadps-2.0#example-1-get-all-groups) or [**Azure CLI**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-group-list) to get the list of Azure AD groups.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i want to access it using python SDK. In AWS we use command line or programmatic access keys using AWS SSO. Do we have anything like that in Azure ?

Comment: Please check this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/groups-operations#BasicoperationsongroupsGetgroups) if it gives you a pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried your code. when I print groups I get an object but when I try the for loop I get error saying azure.graphrbac.models.graph_error_py3.GraphErrorException: Your access token has expired. Please renew it before submitting the request. Any idea about this ?

Comment: Try adding **`resource="https://graph.microsoft.com"`** in the code.

Comment: It is already there in your code snippet. You think I have to make any changes on portal to fix this ?

Comment: Did you grant Microsoft graph API Application permission and granted admin consent to it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246579/discussion-between-user18148705-and-rukminimr-mt).

Comment: Yes sure. Done, Thank you so much for the help means a lot :)